# Switch element positions with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I have 2 DIV's that I have been trying to re-ordered as illustrated on the image below. Trying to move the **Calendar** above **Quick links** for mobile view but it doesn't seem to work. I tried floating the **Calendar** to the left and **Quick links** to the right and it still didn't work. Any ideas on how this can be achieved? I'm open to HTML and jQuery based suggestions.

**HTML**

```
<div id="quick-links"></div><!-- End Quick links -->

<div id="calendar"></div><!-- End Calendar -->
```

**CSS Code**

```
    #calendar {
        float: left;
        position: relative;

         }


    #quick-links {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
}
```

**Illustration image**
[image]

Comment: we at least need the HTML

Comment: If you don't mind supporting modern browsers that understand the CSS3 flexbox specification, that you can use `display: flex` in combination with the `order` attribute.

Comment: For a better crossbrowser result you may also use display: `table-*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Terry, you could make use of CSS3 `Flexbox`.

That way you only have to change the `order`. In fact just change the `order` on one `div` (quicklinks) and it will automatically switch.

Something like this:

```css
#container {
    width: 240px; height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
    /* use column-reverse if needed to reverse the entire list */
}

#quicklinks {
    order: 2;
}

#calendar {
    order: 1;
}

.filler {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 8px;
}

#calendar .filler {
    background-color: #f00;
}
#quicklinks .filler {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="quicklinks">
        <div class="filler">Quick</div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendar">
        <div class="filler">Calendar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/d8r47k8q/

.

Comment: That did it but I changed the flex direction to flex-direction:column-reverse;

Comment: Yup. If you have a list of children and you want to show them in reverse straight-up then `column-reverse` is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to give `display:table` to the the parent of both your div and `display: table-header-group` to the element with the calendar.

Compared to the flexbox approach this ensures a wider compatibility, since it works even on `IE8`

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="quick-links">QuickLinks</div>
  <div id="calendar">Calendar</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { display: table }
#calendar { display: table-header-group }
```

---

Of course you may instead assign `display: table-footer-group` to `quicklinks` element, the final effect would be the same.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBvrZm

Comment: @Chester bear in mind that this solution is 4 y.o. when Flexbox was not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS3 @media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), but you need to determine the screen resolution of the mobile view you are targeting.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="quick-links">QuickLinks</div>
  <div id="calendar">Calendar</div>
</div>
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div#container{
    position: relative;
  }
  #quick-links{ /* move below #calendar*/
    position:absolute;
    top: 115px; /* this should be the height covered the calender height including its margin */
    left: 0
  }

  #calendar{ /* move atop of #quick-links */
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

`max-with: 600px` means that the calendar will be moved to the top of `#quick-links` when viewing in the media screen lower than the resolution width 600px.

Answer (score 0):

```
#calendar{
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#quik-linskr {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```